# Read iframe redirect (same domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm working in writing a chrome extension, and as a result I have the peculiar situation of using non-cross domain Iframes, without the ability to alter the page being displayed in the frame.

When a user clicks a certain link, in he iframe, I want to run some JavaScript.  The default behavior for clicking that link is to load page targetpage.com.  I don't think it's possible, or easy, to read listen for a particular element being clicked inside an iframe

As a workaround, I figure I can check if the iframe reloads, pointing to targetpage.com, and then perform the action.

Note: the action is entirely in the parent page, let's imagine I'm just trying to trigger an alert box.

I know how to trigger JavaScript when an iframe loads.  My three questions are:

1) how can I check the url of an iframe?

2) is there a way to check the iframe, url prior to targetpage.com being loaded. Esther than after?

3) is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to [webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onBeforeNavigate) in background page, it fires when a navigation is about to occur, and you could get `url` and `frameId` in the callback parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer because I haven't played around with this much.

Chrome has a [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) that looks to be something which may come in handy for your extension.

However if you want to get the current domain you're on you'd use...

```
document.domain
```

If you're in a subdirectory of that domain you can grab that with...

```
window.location
```

It also works with an added hash to the url.

If you want the url without the hash you could use `document.referrer` or if you feel hacky you could do something like...

```
var str = window.location
var res = str.toString().split(str.hash)
document.body.innerHTML = res
```